# HTML Positioning of labels and input fields

Tags: html

Im trying to create something like
[this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxORh.png).
each label and input are inside div.
but I need it to be responsive so im not sure how I can do this. Plz assist
UPDATE- my problem is creating label left to input so the all the input will be 100% width and the labels are aligned to right.Also, I need that 2 labels and input will be next to each other ( this is my main problem) in 100% width of the form

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do nice responsive design then maybe you can use some framework to reach your aims. I suggest you to use http://getbootstrap.com/ which is one of the best frameworks to do responsive design.

Comment: forgot to mention Im using bootstrap but its not solving my problems

Comment: then what is your problem? Can you provide some code where do you have issues?

Answer (score 0):

For responsive design you can simply use Bootstrap framework.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

It's all about classes and it should be easy to understand. Alternative for Bootstrap is Zurb Foundation (really nice responsive framework). There is also a third option (not so popular as Bootstrap or Foundation) but still it is a good idea to check it - MDL is an official framework by Google.

[Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

[MDL](http://www.getmdl.io/started/)